# universal windows, c#, await during app initialization

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to port a simple app I had running on Windows Phone 8 to Universal Windows. I have a few files I need to load (locally) before constructing the main frame/page as those instruct how to create the page in the first place. There is a .XML and a few content files that are part of Assets.

I used to do the initialization during the App.Application_Launching() which I guess now is replaced by App.OnLaunched(). The trouble is with the new asynchronous-only file IO I can't seem to find a place where I can call any Async APIs without the program hanging. It appears that anywhere in App.OnLaunched(), MainPage.MainPage(), MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(), etc. I can't use await.

I have to basically fire off a background thread to schedule a task to run later to do the actual initialization, and then call back into the MainPage's pool to get something to run correctly. The resultant code looks something like below. Seems overly complex, but I guess this is correct?

Thanks,
Nick.

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // This doesn't work ...
        // var task = InitAsync();
        // task.Wait()


        // This seems to ...
        IAsyncAction asyncAction = ThreadPool.RunAsync((workItem) =>
        {
            var ignored = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                TryInitAsync();
            });

        });

    }

    private async void TryInitAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await InitAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            int foo = 0;
        }
    }

    private async Task<Boolean> InitAsync()
    {
        // Things that go await in the night

        // Other things that update the layout

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Seems overly complex, but I guess this is correct?

No, I wouldn't say so.

I can't offer specific advice about the initialization itself, since those details are missing from your question. The basic strategy is for the UI to tolerate uninitialized data, and to run the initialization asynchronously, updating properties as needed.

As far as your specific means of starting the asynchronous initialization goes, you have made it more complicated than it needs to or should be. This would be better:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var ignored = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow
        .Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => TryInitAsync());
}
```

I.e. there's no need to start a background task with `ThreadPool.RunAsync()` if all you're going to do is defer your call to the `TryInitAsync()` method, invoking it back on the UI thread.

Doing it this way (or your more complicated way), you are still blocking the UI thread though. It would be even better to *not* use `Dispatcher.RunAsync()`. Instead, *do* call `TryInitAsync()` directly from a background task (e.g. invoke it with `ThreadPool.RunAsync()`) and have the UI-bound properties dependent on the initialization updated asynchronously as the initialization progresses.

Comment: Ah, ok that's what I was trying to find. Essentially something to schedule back on the UI thread at a later time.

Comment: _"something to schedule back on the UI thread at a later time"_ -- that's what the dispatcher `RunAsync()` method will do. It's not the best way, because that will still block the UI thread (just as calling direct from the constructor would), but it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that anywhere in App.OnLaunched(), MainPage.MainPage(), MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(), etc. I can't use await.

The core conceptual change is that modern applications **must** show some kind of UI **immediately** (which means synchronously). This is why you can't do I/O on startup.

So, you have to think about what your app should look like *before* it loads any files, show that state immediately, and also *start* asynchronous loading of your "real" UI.

You could just call `TryInitAsync` directly from your constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  TryInitAsync();
}
```

Or, if you can update your UI with data binding, you could use my [`NotifyTask<T>` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async):

```
public NotifyTask<InitData> Data { get; }
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Data = NotifyTask.Create(InitAsync());
}
private async Task<InitData> InitAsync() { ... }
```

And then you can data-bind to `Data.Result` to get at `InitData`, or `Data.IsCompleted`/`Data.IsNotCompleted` to show/hide the initial "loading..." status.

Comment: I had initially tried calling InitAsync() directly, but making it synchronous would cause the program to hang (although sometimes if would work if stepping through in the debugger). Yes, I do have a default layout that shows immediately, although its effectively just "Loading ..." at the moment. I'll take a look at the NotifyTask<T>.

Comment: @user3799309: In my code, `InitAsync` is called directly, but it is not synchronous.