# KnownFolders.GetFolderAsync never returns in .NET Core 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp, async-await, uno-platform

I am using [Uno Platform](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno) to make an app which access a specific folder inside the user's Documents library from a game (BeamNG.drive). I want the app to read all the mod files inside this folder to be able to edit and display them to users on  startup. I installed the `Nito.Mvvm.Async` Package to help me bind everything to the UI.

Here's part of the method that loads the mod files from the Documents folder:

```cs
public static async Task<List<Mod>> GetModList()
{
    StorageFolder documents = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFolderAsync("BeamNG.drive");
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await documents.GetFilesAsync();

    List<Mod> foundModsList = new();
    
    foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
    {
        //...
    }

    return foundModsList;
}
```

Here's the code on `MainPage.xaml.cs` inside the `Shared` project in my solution, based on code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40109227/8286014)

```cs
public NotifyTask<ObservableCollection<Mod>> ModsData { get; }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ModsData = NotifyTask.Create(InitModData());
}

private static async Task<ObservableCollection<Mod>> InitModData()
{
    return new(await ModManager.GetModList());
}
```

The `GetModList()` method is called, but the `GetFolderAsync("BeamNG.drive")` method never returns, and the app keeps running normally (not UI freezes or anything). If I add a breakpoint in that line, Visual Studio stops there normally. But if I press "Step Over", instead of continuing on that method, VS jumps to this line...

```
return new(await ModManager.GetModList());
```

...then this one:

```
ModsData = NotifyTask.Create(InitModData());
```

Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` in any of the calls using `await` doesn't help anything. I'm really not sure what is going on and I suspect that `Nito.Mvvm.Async` might have something to do with it (considering its last update was in 2017) but I'm really not sure.

Comment: @Dai *"Beginning with C# 9.0, constructor invocation expressions are target-typed. That is, if a target type of an expression is known, you can omit a type name"* ([new operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator))

Answer (score 2):

From your question it seems this problem occurs under .NET 5 - meaning targeting WebAssembly or Skia targets of Uno Platform. Under Uno, the `KnownFolders` type is not yet supported, so accessing `DocumentLibrary` is not possible. If you want to have this supported, please file an issue on [Uno Platform GitHub](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues).

In case of UWP, to access the Documents library, you need to declare a special capability in app manifest (see [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)). However, it is a restricted capability and it is quite likely that if you utilize it, the app will not pass Microsoft Store certification. Instead, it is recommended to use `FolderPicker` instead and let the user decide on the location when files are stored, or to use `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` to store the data for the app privately.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I already had the capability added in my Manifest but I didn't know that Uno doesn't support KnownFolders.My goal is to make a webapp that interacts with a specific application (a folder from a game named BeamNG.drive) which is always located on the user's Documents library. I could use a folder picker but it would be very user-friendly if the app just loaded info from that specific folder. Do you know of any other way that this could be done in a Uno Platform app?

Comment: Retrieving the folder on each platform should be possible, albeit in platform-specific way (as the folder also has a different location and purpose on each). I would suggest using platform specific code and try to access the folder path his way. Check the docs on platform-specific C# code here - https://platform.uno/docs/articles/platform-specific-csharp.html